# Text auto resize to fit a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, scaling, size

I need to autoscale a text to fit inside a static node which can't change its size.

The code I'm actually using is

```
\node[text width=3.75cm] at (0.5*\width,\titley) {
        \begin{center}
            \color{white}\uppercase{\normalsize \textbf{#1}}
        \end{center}
    };
```

The result I'm having is this:

[image: Actual output]

I want the text will not exceed the node without manually resize it.

Thanks to any help!

Comment: `\resizebox` works inside nodes: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) rectangle (3.75,1);
\node[text width=3.75cm,align=center,text=white] at (0.5*3.75,0.5) {
            \resizebox{3.75cm}{!}{\MakeUppercase{\normalsize \textbf{abcded}}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`. It is however not clear to me what the purpose is, do you want to write a macro (and hence the argument `#1`)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I've updated the question. The piece of code comes from a macro.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a `tcboxfit` from `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\tcboxfit[width=5cm, height=2cm, halign=center, valign=center, 
      colback=gray!50, colupper=white, colframe=tcbcolback]
      {\uppercase{This is my box}}

\tcboxfit[width=5cm, height=2cm, halign=center, valign=center, 
      colback=gray!50, colupper=white, colframe=tcbcolback]
      {\uppercase{This is my box with a long long long long 
        long long long long long long long long long long text}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think they were looking specifically for way of doing it using tikz; it's one of the tags